# How can I estimate Cassandra 3.x Secondary Indexes using disk spaces?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have encountered trouble with estimation that uses disk spaces by Cassandra 3.x's 
secondary indexes.

I had seen the answer by Tyler Hobbs here (
["How are Cassandra's 0.7 Secondary Indexes stored?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684564/how-are-cassandras-0-7-secondary-indexes-stored)),
but the version was 0.7.

Is the estimate formuler for ver.0.7 available on ver.3.x?

Appreciate your help with this.
Thank you.

PS.
Mar. 13,2020
I got the answer from "yukim" on Japanese version of stackoverflow.
Thank you.